# EF Core 5: TrackGraph update many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Is it possible to update an EF Core 5.0 many-to-many collection from a detached object?

Let's say we have `Blog` and `Tag` models, with a many-to-many relationship.

I'm trying to save a detached blog with the following code:

```cs
int UpdateBlog(Blog blog)
{
  db.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(blog, node =>
  {
    if (node.Entry.Entity == blog)
      node.Entry.State = node.Entry.IsKeySet ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
    else
    {
      // I don't want to save tags attached to the blog, just update the EF skip navigation.
      node.Entry.State = node.Entry.Unchanged;
    }
  });
  db.SaveChanges();
  return blog.Id;
}
```

This mostly works: `Blog` is inserted or updated. When inserting a new blog, `Tags` collection is properly inserted as well.
But I can't find a way to update the `Tags` collection when updating an existing blog!

I've checked that `entry.Navigation("Tags").IsModified` is indeed true (and according to the docs, that means it will be saved). `IsLoaded` is `false` but changing it to `true` doesn't make a difference either.

Given EF doesn't have the current collection state, I'm expecting it to do a complete `DELETE` and then `INSERT` the current values. Is that impossible to achieve without properly loading the collection? That would seriously limit the usefulness of `TrackGraph`!

Answer (score 2):

After more debugging and reading the EF Core source code, I think the answer is: "no, it's not possible to update a many-to-many collection (or any collection for that matter?) without loading it properly first".

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/ac2bb48b10ecf1289b568a94b7a35e8075c6d787/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/ChangeDetector.cs#L312-L366

It seems that unlike NHibernate, EF can't update a collection that's not loaded first so that it can do a diff (NHibernate handle this case by deleting and re-creating everything).

This in turn makes it rather a pain to update such a detached graph. If someone knows a simple, efficient and generic way to do it I would gladly take the answer!